# Not able to understand issue.in react translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, internationalization, i18next

I am not able to understand the error in my react class component.

[image]

I have to use translation for that I have created below file.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
// import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  // .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    // we init with resources
    resources: {
      en: {
        translations: {
          Accueil: 'Home',
          Projets: 'Work',
          Graphisme: 'Design',
          Web: 'Web',
          Contact: 'Contact',
          // "Projets":"Work",
          'Bienvenue sur notre Blog': 'Welcome to our Blog',
        },
      },
      fr: {
        translations: {
          Accueil: 'Accueil',
          Projets: 'Projets',
          Graphisme: 'Graphisme',
          Web: 'Web',
          Contact: 'Contact',
          // "Projets":"Projets",
          'Bienvenue sur notre Blog': 'Bienvenue sur notre Blog',
        },
      },
    },
    fallbackLng: 'fr',
    debug: true,

    // have a common namespace used around the full app
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',

    keySeparator: false, // we use content as keys

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

I am using in react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import i18n from '../../../i18n';

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
   render(){
       const { t } = this.props;
      return(
          {t('Accueil')}
         )    
}
  }
```

I am not able to understand from where this error is coming.
Could you please, please help me on the same.

Below is the `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start": "dotenv -e .env -- webpack-dev-server --hot --define process.env.dev --inline --port 80 --host localhost",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --env.prod"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "bowser": "^2.1.0",
        "classnames": "^2.1.3",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
        "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.4",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "fbemitter": "^2.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "findup-sync": "^0.1.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "html-react-parser": "^0.4.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
        "i18next": "^21.6.3",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
        "moment": "^2.13.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
        "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
        "react-anything-sortable": "^1.7.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
        "react-bootstrap-date-picker-thecodingmachine": "^5.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap-slider": "^2.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.1.5",
        "react-color": "^2.13.8",
        "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
        "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
        "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
        "react-modal": "^3.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scrollable-anchor": "^0.6.1",
        "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
        "react-signature-pad": "^0.0.6",
        "react-spinners": "^0.4.5",
        "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
        "react-stepzilla": "^4.6.3",
        "react-textarea-autosize": "^5.1.0",
        "react-toastify": "^3.1.0",
        "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
        "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
        "reactjs-localstorage": "0.0.5",
        "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
        "reflux": "^6.4.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "superagent": "^3.8.1",
        "transform-class-properties": "^1.0.0-beta",
        "url-loader": "0.6.2",
        "xss": "^0.3.4"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel": "6.23.0",
        "babel-core": "6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
        "babel-register": "6.26.0",
        "canvas": "1.6.7",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "dotenv-cli": "2.0.1",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
        "immutable": "^3.8.1",
        "jsdom": "11.2.0",
        "mocha": "^3.3.0",
        "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
        "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.10.12",
        "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
        "react-tools": "0.13.3",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "source-map": "^0.6.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
      }
```

I can provide more details if it helps.

Comment: This stack trace is hard to understand because it is generated from minified code. How do you start the app? Seeing your **package.json** might help.

Comment: Thank you @tromgy .I have attached package.json file

Comment: So you don't have any `"scripts"` in **package.json**? What command do you use to start the app?

Comment: I use yarn start

Comment: I don't see this or any other scripts in the **package.json** you posted. You should try to get it run _un_-minified code. Normally that what would `"start": "react-scripts start"` script do, in a CRA-generated project.

Comment: Hi, I actually skipped that part looking at long length of question. I have attached now

Comment: So you're using a production build, that's why you get minimized code. You can add another entry to scripts, like `"build-dev": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js"`, and build with this, see if it produces the build that has "normal", un-minimized code. Then it should be easier to find the source of the error.

Comment: sure..thank you tromgy..let me try the same.